# using proguard with google analytics android

Tags: android, google-analytics, obfuscation, proguard

Does anyone have any idea whether the google android analytics can be obfuscated or not.
If it can be obfuscated, is there any special keep options i have to mention?

Answer (score 3):

You can preserve the jar file using

```
-libraryjars /libs/libGoogleAnalytics.jar
```

Moreover, you can keep the library package in this way:

```
-keep class com.google.android.apps.analytics.**{ *; }
```